# shutil.move IOError: [Errno 2] - When in loop

Tags: python, shutil

If I run shutil.move(file, dest) on its own it works fine, the problem I'm having is when I loop through, the loop works fine without the shutil.move.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'

path = '/media/usb/Test/'
dest = '/media/usb/Done/'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, file)
    f = open( fullpath , 'r')
    dataname = f.name
    print dataname

    shutil.copy(file, dest)
```

I know that this is something simple and I've tried a number of different things but just can't get my head around this.

Comment: Apologies, I tried both and mistyped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving `shutil.copy` the filename (`file`), and not the full path, so it can find the file.

Maybe you meant :

```
shutil.copy(fullpath, dest)
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! I did want to use shutil.move so that the file was removed from the Test folder. But when i do `shutil.move(fullpath, dest)` I get `Error: Destination path already exists` Is there a way round this? Or a better way to delete the file once it has been moved?

Comment: I have added `os.remove(fullpath)` after `shutil.copy(fullpath, dest)` and all is working, thanks for your help.