# Unable to move mp4 files to another directory in ubuntu using python

Tags: python

I am having difficulty moving mp4 files from one directory to another (Ubuntu Linux). The code i have included herewith seems to work perfectly when I move .py files between directory's.  I have done some research on Google searching for an answer but to no avail. i have found answers pointing to permissions etc and i have found help from the following urls.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193015/shutil-move-ioerror-errno-2-when-in-loop`

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432197/python-recursive-find-files-and-move-to-one-destination-directory`

I am new to python and just learning.  please can you assist with the code i have included and with the error message i get when i run my python script to move .mp4 files.

`sudo python defmove.py /home/iain/dwhelper /home/iain/newfolder .mp4`

(i am running the script from the directory where the defmove.py script resides and i have also made sure that newfolder does not exist prior to running defmove.py)

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

def movefiles(src,dest,ext):
    if not os.path.isdir(dest):
        os.mkdir(dest)
            for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
                for f in files:
                    if f.endswith(ext):
                         shutil.move(f,dest)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print 'incorrect number of paramaters'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
         src  = sys.argv[1]
         dest = sys.argv[2]
         ext  = sys.argv[3]
         movefiles(src,dest,ext)
```

main()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "defmove.py", line 24, in <modeule>
   main()
  File "defmove.py", line 22, in main
    movefiles(src,dest,ext)
  File "defmove.py", line 11, in movefiles
    shutil.move(f,dest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 301, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src,dest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No suck file or directory: 'feelslike.mp4'
```

Comment: Thank you. i just modified my code accordingly and the move was a success.  i am however confused as to why when i moved .py files to another directory rather than .mp4 files it worked. I only seemed to get the above error message when I tried to move only .mp4 files.  are you able to provide an explanation for this....?

Answer (score 1):

When python I/O is given a filename, it assumes that the file is in the current directory, or somewhere on it's path; if it's not in any of those places, it yields an `IOError`. Therefore, when you are accessing files in directories other than your current directory, it's important to specific the path to that file.

In your code, calling `shutils.move` with `f` is just supplying the function a file name---the path to that filename has been stripped off. Therefore, your call to `shutils.move` should look like

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), dest)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I now understand how and why it was going wrong when trying to move .mp4 files as they were in another directory from my python scripts.